# Cannot switch to Gnome on 16.04

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I have it already on my laptop with Gnome 3.20 working. My desktop pc has an i7 4790 and AMD HD 7950 installed the Gnome 3.20 and rebooted. Now I have the icon to switch between unity and gnome but if I click on it the menu stays empty and I can't do anything, I have to hit enter go back to password input.

How can I solve this? Or how can i switch the default desktop environment cause i already tried editing `50-ubuntu.conf` in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` without any luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem solved it by switching to gdm3 and then the gear icon worked
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` - this command allows you to switch to gdm3